# Selecting k distinct numbers from an array with increasing probability distribution

Tags: probability, algorithms, sampling

I have to select k distinct numbers from an array such that probability of a number getting selected is more if it is at the end of the array (probability increases linearly). I'm thinking of assigning probability to each number as

`current_position_of_number_in_array/(n*(n+1)/2)`

where n is the size of the given array. Then generate a random number between 0 and 1 and selecting the number in array which falls into that range. This will work fine if I have to select non-distinct numbers, but in case I have to select distinct numbers, this won't be efficient if size of k is of the order of n.(assuming I'm using some kind of hash-set to discard repeated numbers)

Are there better algorithms to select k distinct numbers which are of better big-oh complexity ?

Comment: Probably. You would probably have better luck asking this at http://programmers.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @CarlHeckman No, it's better asked as a math question.

Comment: $k$ being of the order of $n$ isn't a problem. The approach you suggest only becomes inefficient if $k$ approaches $n$.

Comment: @joriki Agreed. Main problem is if k approaches n, then probability of selecting repeated number becomes very high and to ensure that k unique numbers are selected, I might have to repeat this procedure too many times.

Comment: What sort of complexity are you aiming for? I think the approach you describe should take $O(n^2\log n)$ expected time in the case $k=n$. I could describe one that takes $O(n^2)$, if that helps -- or are you looking for something like $O(n\log n)$?

Comment: I'm looking for something of the order of O(n log n) or better

Comment: Note that an alternative way to choose a single number with linearly increasing probability is to choose two distinct numbers and use the larger one. (To get the same probabilities as you have, starting with $1$ and not with $0$, you'd have to add a dummy least element that gets the $0$ probability.) Perhaps you can somehow use this in selecting $k$ numbers.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I can probably use something like Floyd’s sampling Algorithm to select 2 numbers every time and select the larger one (O(k lg (k) ) complexity ?). Is there any proof that I can look up to ensure that this algorithm will select numbers with linearly increasing probability ?

Comment: It selects numbers with linearly increasing probability because the number $j$ is the larger element of $j$ pairs, and all pairs are selected with equal probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally ended up using weighted reservoir sampling with uniformly increasing weights.

Here is a detailed paper: http://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf

Implementation in Java: http://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/projects/WRS/

Answer (score 2):

As I pointed out in a comment, you can choose a single number with linearly increasing probability by choosing two distinct numbers and using the larger one. (This gives probability $0$ for the least element, so you need to add a dummy least element to get exactly the probabilities you describe.)

To use this for efficiently selecting $k$ distinct elements with linear probabilities, set up an array originally containing all $n$ numbers. Then in each step, select $i$ uniformly randomly between $1$ and $n$ and $j$ uniformly randomly from the numbers remaining in the array. Repeat this until $j\gt i$. Use $j$ as the next number and remove it from the array (in constant time, by overwriting it with the last element of the array and decrementing the array length).

This should select all $n$ numbers in $O(n\log n)$ time. I don't have a rigorous proof for that off the top of my head, but it seems plausible from a coupon collector's perspective. The direct approach you described would take $O(n^2)$ time to select the $1$ if it's the last number left, and I think it would take $O(n^2\log n)$ overall. By contrast, this approach would take $O(n)$ time to select the $1$ if it's the last number left, and thus should take $O(n\log n)$ time overall.

Comment: Come to think of it, this is actually just rejection sampling for the $j$s picked from the array; there's no added benefit in regarding $i$ as the second element of a pair; it's basically just a random number drawn to decide whether to accept $j$ (which means that you can use this to sample from any distribution without repetition, not just for your linear case).

Comment: I finally ended up using weighted reservoir sampling with uniformly increasing weights. http://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf

Comment: @r15habh: That's a beautiful algorithm! Never heard of it. Please write an answer to your question (and accept it) in case someone else has a similar question.